# Nodejs + Q promise + method return based on url type

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, url, q

I am using node js for backend, also using q promise package.

Question : I am trying to get third party product details.
1. www.abcd.com 2. www.xyz.com - this method i handle in backend.

Possible url:

1. localhost:8080/search?type="abcd";
2. localhost:8080/search?type="xyz";
3. localhost:8080/search;

   If the above URL type is **abcd** means need to search some different thridparty(www.abcd.com) http url;

   If the above URL type is **xyz** means need to search some other different thridparty(www.xyz.com) http url

   If the above URL didn't get type means need to search www.abcd.com if the result found means then return response, if result not found means need to call www.xyz.com url and then return response. (Note - here two third party api need to call)

Code:

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {

    if (!( typeof req.query === 'undefined' || req.query === null || req.query == "")) {
        var type = req.query;
    }

    var spec = {
        resp : {}
    };

    Q(spec).then(function(spec) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        var optionsget = {
            host : 'abcd.com',
            method : 'GET'
        };

        var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
            var getProductInfo = '';
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                getProductInfo += d;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                if (( typeof message == 'undefined') && (!( typeof items === 'undefined' || items === null))) {
                    spec.resp.list = items;
                    deferred.resolve(spec);
                } else {
                    spec.resp.message = message;
                    deferred.reject(spec);
                }
            });

        });
        reqGet.end();
        reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            deferred.reject(spec);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }).then(function(spec) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        var optionsget = {
            host : 'xyz.com',
            method : 'GET'
        };

        var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
            var getProductInfo = '';
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                getProductInfo += d;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                if (( typeof message == 'undefined') && (!( typeof items === 'undefined' || items === null))) {
                    spec.resp.list = items;
                    deferred.resolve(spec);
                } else {
                    spec.resp.message = message;
                    deferred.reject(spec);
                }
            });

        });
        reqGet.end();
        reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            deferred.reject(spec);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }).then(function(spec) {
        spec.resp.status = 'Success';
        res.send(spec.resp);
    }).fail(function(spec) {
        spec.resp.status = 'Error';
        res.send(spec.resp);
    });

});
```

I this is chilly question. I understand need to check the type and implement. I thought we need to add some different function for both (abcd  and xyz) then can call that method based on type.

Please suggest to good way.